# Поиск перекрестных совпадений с помощью регулярных выражений

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Добрый вечер. Понимаю, что вопрос очень глупый, но голова уже не варит. Да, начинается время зачетов :)

Для N-ной лабы по матстату нужно посчитать количество вхождений подстроки в строку. Банальщина. Чтобы эту банальщину хоть как-то приукрасить, пишем extension method для string:

```
public static int P(this string baseStr, string inputStr)
{
    return new Regex(inputStr).Matches(baseStr).Count;
}
```

Для справки - в задании строка из N 0 и 1, первым этапом надо посчитать вероятности появления пар в строке.

Собственно, мой глупый вопрос: почему описанный метод, вызванный от строки "1111" возвращает 2? Ну не могут же регулярки последовательно считать...

**UPD:**

пример вызова метода:

```
string data = "1111";
Console.WriteLine(data.P("11")); //2
```

Comment: Не очень понятно, к какой строке вы применяете метод, и с каким аргументом. "1111" - это строка, к которой вы применяете метод, или это аргумент метода? И что такое " строка из N 0 и 1"?

Comment: @DreamChild, обновил вопрос.

Comment: Конец предыдущего совпадения является началом нового совпадения, поэтому результат 2, а не 3.  
Найти все совпадения можно прибегнув к опережающей проверке:  

    data.P("(?=11)")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всё верно: в строке `1111` всего два вхождения подстроки `11`. Регулярные выражения анализируют текст слева направо. При совпадении внутренний "курсор" (индекс) устанавливается на его начальную позицию. Следущее совпадение система начинает искать с позиции, находящейся сразу после текущего совпадения. Таким образом, перекрёстные совпадения невозможны при использовании обычных шаблонов.

Как верно заметил ReinRaus, необходимо воспользоваться механизмом опережающей проверки, т.е. конструкцией `(?=...)`, которая используется для *проверки* того, что следует после текущей позиции в строке. Несмотря на то, что такие блоки не "поглощают" текст при совпадении (т.е. при нахождении подстроки индекс остаётся на прежнем месте во входной строке), внутри них возможно использование захватывающих подмасок типа `(...)`.

Тут мы подходим к решению проблемы:

```
string data = "1111";
string sub = "11";
Console.WriteLine(data.P(string.Format("(?=({0}))", Regex.Escape(sub)));
```

Здесь [пример использования данного подхода](http://ideone.com/KR0xjh).

Comment: Раз Вы решили сделать универсальное решение через подстановку, то не забудьте, что нужно экранировать мета-символы.

Comment: @ReinRaus: Я просто засмотрелся на пример, в котором все символы — цифры :)

Answer (score 0):

Потому что вхождения не могут пересекаться. Надо делать предпросмотр, чтобы сжирать только то, что не входит в искомую строку:

```
(?=11)
```