# Вхождение выражения в строку

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, строки

Необходимо найти все позиции вхождения шаблона в строке. Шаблон выглядит как: **"a?b"**, где **'?'** означает любой символ.
Пытаюсь  заменить **'?'** на **'.'** и воспользоваться поиском первого вхождения регулярного выражения в строке  **indexOf**, но вхождения почему-то не обнаружены:

```
        str = scan.nextLine();
        shablon = scan.nextLine();
        int j = -1;
        String p = shablon.replace('?', '.');
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            j = str.indexOf(p, i);
            if (j >= 0) {
                System.out.print(j + " ");
            }
        }
```

**Input**
abacaba
a?a
**Output** (ожидаемый)
1 3 5
**Реальный выход** - пустая строка (потому что все значения функции равны **-1**)

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Упомянули регулярки, а сами ищете подстроку в строке http://proglang.su/java/strings-indexof?category=java&alias=116

Comment: у вас p="a.a", а такого в исходной строке нету, у вас каждая иттерация ищет `a.a` во все строке и паттерн не указан

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы ищете подстроку в строке. Эта функция `.indexOf` не работает в регулярками., то бишь на входе строка.

```
    String STR = "abacaba";
    String PATTERN = "(a.?a)";

    Pattern P = Pattern.compile(PATTERN);
    Matcher M = P.matcher(STR);

    while (M.find()) {
       System.out.println(M.group(1));
       System.out.println(M.start() + " - " + (M.end()-1));
    }
```

Результат:

```
aba
0 - 2
aba
4 - 6
```

Comment: Нет ещё одного варианта, используйте способ из https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/274673/Поиск-перекрестных-совпадений-с-помощью-регулярных-выражений

Comment: @ReinRaus если что Java и C# разные языки.

Comment: Почитайте что-нибудь про PCRE

Comment: @ReinRaus зачем так усложнять? тут стандартный функционал. А для PCRE ещё и либу ставить нужно.

Comment: Вы ошибаетесь. И в Java и в С#-  PCRE.

Comment: @ReinRaus я в курсе. но для Java надо ещё ставить либу.

Comment: какую? Из коробки есть пцре (без некоторых функций не нужных для решения данной задачи).

Comment: @ReinRaus, с чего бы там PCRE? Предпросмотр назад в шарпе есть, да и в джаве, кажется, тоже...

Comment: А что такое PCRE? Какие виды регулярных выражений есть ещё? Вопросы лёгкие и найти самостоятельно ответ на них эффективнее, чем я буду растекаться мыслию по древу :-)

Answer (score 0):

Для решения задачи следуйте алгоритму:

1. Преобразуйте Ваш шаблон в эквивалентное регулярное выражение
2. Если шаблон будет вводить пользователь, то не забывайте про экранирование мета-символов регулярных выражений
3. Полученное регулярное выражение поместите внутри конструкции `(?=...)` в случае из вопроса регулярное выражение будет выглядеть так: `(?=a.?a)`

Полученный результат будет показывать позицию вхождения шаблона с учетом того, что вхождения могут перекрывать друг друга.

Answer (score 0):

```
   private void Method(string value, string template)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
        {
            bool flag = true;
            int index = i;
            for (int j = 0; j < template.Length; j++)
            {
                if (index < value.Length && template[j] != '?' && value[index] == template[j] ||template[j] == '?')
                {
                    index++;
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    flag = false;
                    break;
                }                   
            }
            if(flag)
                Console.WriteLine(i);

        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```